# Updating Libreoffice on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice, software-updates

So I'm currently in internship and we work with Linux Mint.

I have never worked with Mint before, so I have no idea how some things work. My boss gave me a project to make a guide on how to update Libreoffice from the terminal, and eventually make it an executable file so people on other machines can simply click the executable file and have libreoffice instantly updated to the latest version. However, I do not know what the right commands are, I have tried this so far:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

and

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

They only work on Linux Mint version 18, but on version 17 I get errors. Sometimes it says it has been updated while it has not and I just get pretty frustrated because I want to show my potential to my boss, any help please?

Comment: What version do you want to update it to? `sudo apt-get install libreoffice` will update to the latest available in the repository. Isn't that enough? And what errors do you get? We can't really help if you don't tell us the errors you see.

Comment: The add repo version upgraded my linuxmint to current latest early adopter version, thanks, not quite sure the default updater doesn't do this

Answer (score 0):

There is usually the newest version of libreoffice available from snapcraft.

`sudo apt install snapd`

`sudo snap install libreoffice`